# PHP reset form/POST data on refresh

Tags: php, forms

So, this is part of the code for my login form:

```
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) != '') {
        header ("Location: home.php");
    }

    require_once ('dbconnect.php');

        if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
    {
        $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$uname."'");
        $num = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);


            if ($num > 0)  { 
                ?>
                    <script>alert('Duplicate username');</script>
                <?php

            }
                else {  ...

    }
```

The problem is, when duplicate username is entered, i receive an Duplicate username error message, and on every refresh form is reset, but error is repeatedly there.

```
print_r ($num);
```

on refresh returns array with last entered form name. 
I would like to preserve error message for the first time, but afterwards i would like to reset form data, or somehow reset the SQL query or variable that contains it, so error message wont be repeating itself on refresh.

Any suggestion are welcome,

thx

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` return array of result set not total number of rows. You can use `mysql_num_rows()` to get number of rows.

Comment: Thx for the hint, but that doesnt solve my issue ...

Comment: Can you post your form code???

Comment: `<form method="post">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Name" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr
<td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Me Up</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="index.php">Sign In Here</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_num_rows()` to get number of rows.

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$uname."'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```